# Is it possible to use React Hooks API without using JSX (in typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jsx

When translating JSX version React Hooks API [demo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) into the one without JSX, following [react-without-jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html), I got the following code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export function test() {
  ReactDOM.render(Count(), document.getElementById('main'));
}

export function Count() {
  const e = React.createElement;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const button = e('button', {
    onClick: () => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    },
  });
  return e('div', null, e('p', `You clicked ${count} times`), button);
}
```

However, when running this code in the browser, I got the following error

```
react.development.js:1551 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1551)
    at Object.useState (react.development.js:1582)
    at Count (Count.ts:10)
    at Object.test (Count.ts:5)
    at main (index.ts:4)
    at Object../src/index.ts (index.ts:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1551
useState @ react.development.js:1582
Count @ Count.ts:9
test @ Count.ts:4
main @ index.ts:3
./src/index.ts @ index.ts:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:18
```

If use JSX, the above example works fine.

All examples of function components seem to be based on JSX. 
So is it possible to use React Hook without JSX? If it is possible, how can we do that?

---

**Edit updated:** code above still has a mistake (as described in the following edit).

The

```
e('p', `You clicked ${count} times`)
```

should be

```
e('p', null, `You clicked ${count} times`)
```

second argument of `createElement` should be props.

---

**Edit by following instructions by @qxg.**

During render, I didn't use `React.createElement`, by modify code to

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export function test() {
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Count), document.getElementById('main'));
}

// ... Same code for Count as above
```

The calling Hooks API outside function component error was solved!

However, there are new errors like:

```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `0`    react-dom.development.js:82
    in p (created by Count)
    in div (created by Count)
    in Count
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `1`    react-dom.development.js:82
    in p (created by Count)
    in div (created by Count)
    in Count
```

lots of errors like above, ending with

```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `18`   react-dom.development.js:82 
    in p (created by Count)
    in div (created by Count)
    in Count
```

The page was rendered as

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Thus only empty elements, no texts.
Any advice for this problem?

---

p.s. I'm not sure if there are configuration of typescript/webpack errors, so I post them here.

ts.config.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,

    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,

    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
  devtool: 'source-map',

  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!-- Main -->
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you remove the import `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`? Does that work?

Comment: Should you call `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Count, ...`?

Comment: @John I can not remove the import of `ReactDOM`, I need to use `ReactDOM.render(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You manually converted jsx to React.creatElement but forgot to convert top level element as well.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Count), document.getElementById('main'));
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for solving calling Hooks API outside function component error. Unfortunately, there are new errors, I've updated the question to describe new problems.

Comment: I got the mistake left, when create <p>, my arguments is wrong. Except this, the problem of functional component is solved by exactly what you suggested. Thx.

Comment: I experienced the same problem. I guess `React.createElement` serves as a meta-function that converts some function that **returns a react element**, to a function that **is itself a react element and returns a react element**. My assumption is that the difference between a plain function and a React functional component is that the React component has additional fields and functions attached to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete working example

```
<div id='main'></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script>
const e = React.createElement;
function Count() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const button = e('button', {onClick: ()=>setCount(count+1)}, 'Click!');
  return e('div', null, e('p', null, `You clicked ${count} times`), button);
}
ReactDOM.render(e(Count), document.getElementById('main'));
</script>
```